# How can I get the recodetype name in trigger Handler?

Tags: apex, trigger, servicecloud

Unable to get recordType name by this.triggerNew[0].recordType.Name.It is return null.

```
 public CustomerInfoHandler() {
        this.triggerNew = (List<CustomerInfo__c>) Trigger.new;
    }

    public override void beforeInsert() {
        String customerID = this.triggerNew[0].recordType.Name + getToday() + '-' + getAutoNumber(this.triggerNew[0].recordType.Name);
        this.triggerNew[0].customerID__c = customerID;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access parent objects without obtaining them somehow. Since we're talking about record types, you can:

```
// Static variable inside class, outside method
static Map<Id, RecordTypeInfo> recordTypes = sObjectType.CustomerInfo__c.getRecordTypeInfosById();
public override void beforeInsert() {
  String recordTypeName = recordTypes.get(this.triggerNew[0].RecordTypeId)?.getName();
  String customerID = recordTypeName + getToday() + '-' + getAutoNumber(recordTypeName);
  this.triggerNew[0].customerID__c = customerID;
}
```

Note that you should make sure this method is bulkified.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get `RecordTypeName` or `RecordTypeDeveloperName` directly from trigger.

Instead try creating a util class.

```
    public String getRecordTypeDeveloperNameFromId(Schema.SObjectType sObjType, Id recordTypeId, String sObjectAsString) {
        initialize(sObjType, sObjectAsString);
        if (mapRecordTypeById.get(sObjectAsString).containsKey(recordTypeId)) {
            Schema.RecordTypeInfo recordTypeInfo = mapRecordTypeById.get(sObjectAsString).get(recordTypeId);
            return recordTypeInfo.getDeveloperName();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void initialize(Schema.SObjectType sObjType, String sObjectAsString) {
        if (!mapRecordTypeByName.containsKey(sObjectAsString) || !mapRecordTypeById.containsKey(sObjectAsString)) {
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeObjectResult = sObjType.getDescribe();
            mapRecordTypeByName.put(sObjectAsString, describeObjectResult.getRecordTypeInfosByName());
            mapRecordTypeById.put(sObjectAsString, describeObjectResult.getRecordTypeInfosById());
            mapRecordTypeByDeveloperName.put(sObjectAsString, describeObjectResult.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName());
        }
    }
```

And then use it like below.

`System.debug(YOURCLASS.getRecordTypeDeveloperNameFromId(Case.getSObjectType(), 'RecordTypeIdFromTrigger', 'Case'));`

You can pass the Id of the record type and it will fetch you the record type developername.